# What to put as a selector in CSS? Accounts-entry with Meteor

Tags: html, css, meteor, accounts

I'm using the accounts-entry package with my meteor project and want to customize the `{{> entrySignUp}}` and `{{> entrySignIn}}`. What do I put as a selector in CSS to do this? I tried putting them in a `<div>` but it didn't make a difference? Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at packages/accounts-entry/client/views/signUp in your project to see the templates used.  Or just use the browser developer tools to inspect the dom.  Either way, you should be able to find the ids and classes you need to override in your styles.

The views have been designed to work well with bootstrap 3, but theres nothing stopping you from customizing it.